# Does buoyant force acts on fully submerged objects?

Tags: forces, free-body-diagram, buoyancy, fluid-statics

If the object completely settle down at the bottom of the vessel than also it experience buoyant force?

Comment: The surface integral of the pressure over the boundary of the object is then no longer equal to the buoyant force, because a normal force will now be exerted on the lower boundary that is in contact with the bottom of the vessel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the buoyant force on a cube at the bottom of a tank of water manifest itself?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/59866/)

Answer (score 4):

Yes. [Archimedes' principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes'_principle) tells us that:

> the upward buoyant force that is exerted on a body immersed in a fluid, **whether fully or partially submerged**, is equal to the weight of the fluid that the body displaces and acts in the upward direction at the centre of mass of the displaced fluid

If your submerged body was resting on  set of scales, the force measured by the scales would be the weight of the body minus the weight of water displaced by the body.

Comment: This answer contradicts the answer in the duplicate question. Also, what would be supplying the upward force if there was no fluid from below to push up on the object?