# Wood vs static Water

Tags: water, density, buoyancy, fluid-statics

First of all: I'am not a physicist or anything close to it. I jhust enjoy to think about certain thinks in a different way and to ask for a much more detailed "how".

So here is what keeps me from sleeping recently:

1. wood floats on water (usually)
2. to float on the water the water needs a way to get under the wood
3. both materials are "pulled down" by gravity
4. due to the higher density the water gets "pulled down more"

If there would be a piece of wood which has a 100% flat surface and you would place it a few centimeter deep and 100% horizontal in a 100% static water.
Would it float "up" to the waters surface to float as usual or will it be blocked by the water which can't get under the wood?

Comment: Do you mean the water gets pulled down more in item #4?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/59866/)