# Will buoyancy act on B?

Tags: forces, fluid-statics, buoyancy

A is immersed in water, buoyancy must act on A; B is at the bottom of the container, there is no water between B and the container, that is to say, the bottom of B is not in contact with water, so will buoyancy act on B? Some people say buoyancy works on B, but I don't think so. B is like a suction hook. Water presses B on the bottom of the container. Buoyancy does not act on B.
I'm not sure I'm absolutely right.
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the buoyant force on a cube at the bottom of a tank of water manifest itself?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/59866/)

Comment: I agree with your thinking.  As does the marked duplicate.  That said, Engineering SE seems to think the opposite for some reason https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/19159/ but I contested it quite a bit.  I think most people weren't considering this edge case when writing the answers there.

Comment: If the mass of B is less than the mass of the water it displaces then what? Archimedes.

Comment: @SolarMike Archimedes' principle relies on the assumption that there _is_ fluid beneath the submerged object, as it's the overall net hydrostatic pressure gradient that causes the upward force.  This is talking about the case where there is _no_ fluid between the bottom of B and the containers surface.  It can not be treated as a submerged object, as it does not have a distribution of pressure across all the surfaces.  You could do a force balance and see that it could only be pushed down.  For objects with fluids on all sides, the pressure balance works out to Archimedes' principle.

Comment: @JMac so if you have a container with a polished base and a hollow cube which has a mass less than the volume of water it displaces with a polished surface to assume no water between and you place the cube on the base, then fill with water, it is your assertion that the cube will not begin to float ...

Comment: @SolarMike Yes, that is exactly what would happen, if you could manage to get that perfect seal.  Archimedes' principle is really just an easy rule for buoyant force for objects submerged in a fluid.  If you take a sample object in a hydrostatic incompressible medium and find the net force acting on it due to the pressure distribution, you will see the same results as with Archimedes' principle.  When you assume the bottom does not have pressure acting on it, the assumptions of the principle no longer hold, and it cannot be applied.

Comment: @JMac I can get a perfect seal : weld all the way round... Those suction hooks fail once the load on them exceeds a certain value...

Comment: @SolarMike Not clear what you're getting at?  If you weld a box to the surface of a container, then fill it with water, the welded part wont try to float if it's a full seal, it will just be pushed  down more by the fluid on top of it.

Comment: @SolarMike You don't agree with me?

Comment: Your question is equivalent to asking whether it possible to stick a buoyant object to the bottom of a tub of water by using a suction cup. That's an experiment that you can try at home.

Comment: @SolomonSlow You would be surprised how many people actually contest this.  Just look at how people tried to answer it on Engineering SE https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19159/would-an-object-at-the-bottom-of-the-sea-still-experience-buoyancy  The correct answer was downvoted enough to be the lowest answer.

Answer (score 2):

If  there is perfectly no water under B(not even a thin film), probably if B is joined at the base and then water is poured, then there will be no buoyancy. But if water somehow reaches below B, even a thin film, which is the practical case if no appropriate precautions are taken, then buoyancy will act on B.

Comment: If the liquid is very thin, buoyancy will not work on B.

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely correct . There will be no buoyant force acting on B . Buoyant force is basically a result of pressure differences on the two surfaces of a immersed body. Generally as the fluid is present below an object so at the bottom surface of the object there is more pressure than the pressure at the top surface (due difference in height. So basically if the height of immersed solid is $h$ so there is a pressure difference of $\rho gh$ (if $\rho$ is the density of the fluid )which provides the upward buoyant force. The force can be given as $\rho ghA$
which  further simplifies to give $\rho gV$ (where V is the volume of solid **immersed** in water)

Answer (score 0):

If the tank is rigid enough and the adhesion is not destroyed by other things (vibrations, air in the water...), so no water gets below the bottom face of B, then the pressure forces will act on the block B in such a way as to push the block down, with force equal to

$$
\text{pressure at the top face} \times \text{face area}.
$$

So instead of being lighter, the block will be heavier (to lift up) than in the air. The effect could be named *anti-buoyancy*.

If somebody tried to lift the block, they may need much bigger force than $mg$ + the above force, because of the additional force of adhesion between the bottom face and the tank.