# Block completely immersed inside the fluid

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

Consider a block with density $\sigma$ kept in liquid of density $\rho$, where $ \rho > \sigma$. Now what is the cause of force by which it moves upwards? Is it buoyant force? If yes, then how? As it seems to me that there no force in the upward direction.

$\hskip2in$[image]

Comment: have a look at https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/478306/207455

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is that the pressure exerted by the fluid varies with depth, according to:

$$P=\rho gh$$

for a fluid with density $\rho$.

Suppose, for simplicity, that our object has two flat, horizontal faces for its top and bottom, with equal area $A$, and suppose it has vertical sides. The object's has a height $y$, meaning that its top and bottom faces are separated by the distance $y$. Suppose the top face is immersed to a depth $h_0$. Then we can calculate the total downward force exerted by the fluid on the top face (pressure always acts normal to the surface of the material, which, since the face is horizontal, is downward):

$$F_{top}=P_{top}A=\rho g h_0 A$$

We can also calculate the total upward force exerted by the fluid on the bottom face of the object:

$$F_{bottom}=P_{bottom}A=\rho g (h_0+y)A$$

since the bottom face is a distance $y$ deeper than the top face, the pressure is greater there. Suppose the object is rigid, so that a force anywhere on the object contributes to the net force on the object without any modification. Then the net buoyant force on the object is the difference of forces on the top and the bottom (the forces on the sides all cancel out with each other, since the force on opposite faces acts at the same height):

$$F_{net}=F_{bottom}-F_{top}=\rho g y A$$

So the net buoyant force is upward.

The above doesn't apply if the object is at the bottom of the container, with absolutely no liquid whatsoever underneath the block, but remember that the fluid surrounding the bottom edge of the block is at a high pressure and will seep into any defect whatsoever in the connection between the bottom edge of the object and the bottom of the container, at which point it will begin to push upward from the bottom, so in most practical circumstances, you cannot get this to happen with normal rigid materials, and buoyancy effectively acts the same on the bottom of the container. In the event that you do have a material that so perfectly conforms to the surface of the bottom of the container that no water can get through, you will likely have cold-welded the material to the bottom with van der Waals forces anyway, at which point there are other forces at play.

Comment: Last paragraph was actually needed thnx

Comment: @pss1 Yeah, I realized after writing the original answer that you were specifically asking about an object on the bottom of the container.

Comment: Note that the force depends on the area times pressure difference, and the pressure difference depends on the height, and height is the volume divided by aforementioned area, making the whole explanation independent of shape.